Camel NotifyBuilder does not match when exception is thrown
It seems that camel's NotifyBuilder works in normal message processing but does not work when exceptions are thrown.
Please see the following test case where I create the following routes

direct:route-a adds "a" to a list and passes to direct:route-b
direct:route-b adds "b" to a list and throws exception
errorHandler routes to direct:dead-letter as a deadLetterChannel
direct:dead-letter adds "dead" to a list

I can see that the list contains "a", "b", "dead" when I send a message to direct:route-a
But the NotifyBuilders for direct:route-b and direct:dead-letter don't match for some reason.
Is there a bug in NotifyBuilder where they don't match when exceptions are thrown? Am I using NotifyBuilder incorrectly? I've tried both NotifyBuilder.whenDone(1) and NotifyBuilder.whenFailed(1) and neither causes a match.
Looking at the NotifyBuilder javadoc I see the following comment for whenDone(...)

The difference between done and completed is that done can also include failed messages, where as completed is only successful processed messages.

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.NotifyBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@Slf4j
public class NotifyBuilderTest {
    private CamelContext camelContext;
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
    private List<String> list;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() throws Exception {
        list = new LinkedList<>();
        camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:route-a")
                        .process(exchange -> list.add("a"))
                        .to("direct:route-b");

                from("direct:route-b")
                        .process(exchange -> list.add("b"))
                        .process(exchange -> { throw new Exception("foo"); });

                errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:dead-letter"));

                from("direct:dead-letter")
                        .process(exchange -> list.add("dead"));
            }
        });
        producerTemplate = new DefaultProducerTemplate(camelContext);

        camelContext.start();
        producerTemplate.start();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void afterEach() {
        producerTemplate.stop();
        camelContext.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotify() {
        NotifyBuilder notifierA = new NotifyBuilder(camelContext)
                .from("direct:route-a")
                .whenDone(1)
                .create();
        NotifyBuilder notifierB = new NotifyBuilder(camelContext)
                .from("direct:route-b")
                .whenDone(1)
                .create();
        NotifyBuilder notifierDead = new NotifyBuilder(camelContext)
                .from("direct:dead-letter")
                .whenDone(1)
                .create();

        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:route-a", null);

        // this succeeds
        assertThat(list).containsExactly("a", "b", "dead");

        // this succeeds
        assertThat(notifierA.matches(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();

        // this fails
        assertThat(notifierB.matches(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();

        // this fails
        assertThat(notifierDead.matches(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
    }
}


It turns out that NotifyBuilder.from(...) only matches the entry point to the pipeline (in my case direct:route-a). I was able to solve my problem by using NotifyBuilder.from(...) to match route-a and NotifyBuilder.wereSentTo(...) to  match the subsequent routes.
I've refactored the test case as follows
@Test
public void testNotify() {
  NotifyBuilder notifierA = new NotifyBuilder(camelContext)
      .from("direct:route-a")
      .whenDone(1)
      .create();
  NotifyBuilder notifierB = new NotifyBuilder(camelContext)
      .wereSentTo("direct:route-b")
      .whenDone(1)
      .create();
  NotifyBuilder notifierDead = new NotifyBuilder(camelContext)
      .wereSentTo("direct:dead-letter")
      .whenDone(1)
      .create();

  producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:route-a", null);

  assertThat(list).containsExactly("a", "b", "dead");
  assertThat(notifierA.matches(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
  assertThat(notifierB.matches(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
  assertThat(notifierDead.matches(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
}

